# Can't remove a sublayer from AVSynchronizedLayer

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

I tried to add a CALayer in my `addLayer` function:

```
@IBAction func addLayer(_ sender: UIButton){
    self.layer = (self.cxeObject?.layer)!
    self.synchLayer = AVSynchronizedLayer(playerItem: self.playerItem!)
    self.synchLayer!.bounds = self.playerView.layer.bounds
    self.synchLayer!.position = self.playerView.layer.position
    self.synchLayer!.addSublayer(self.layer!)
    self.playerView.layer.addSublayer(self.synchLayer!)
}
```

and then I tried to remove the layer in my `removeLayer` function:

```
@IBAction func removeLayer(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
}
```

but it didn't work! When I tried to do this, it worked:

```
self.synchLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
```

but i can't do this, because I have some sublayers in `self.synchLayer`.
Can anyone help me? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my question, When I ran the application on my iPhone, it worked. the code works fine:
`@IBAction func removeLayer(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
}` But I don't know why. Maybe, `AVSynchronizedLayer` doesn't work on the simulator but works on a device.